Why might sympy.solve succeed with respect to fewer variables but fail w.r.t. more variables?
This question concerns surprising behavior from the sympy.solve function applied to systems of equations. The behavior seems almost like a bug, or at least an edge case for which the sympy.solve function might be refined.
For certain systems of equations (e.g., a system of 2 polynomial equations in 3 variables), sympy.solve can find solutions with respect to a subset of the system's variables, but raises an error when asked to solve the same system for a larger set of variables containing that subset (even if the additional variables do not appear in the system!). In theory, a solver should be able to at least find the previous solutions (i.e., those for the smaller subset) augmented by simply letting the additional variables have no constraints, so I would like to understand why such examples cause the error to be raised. The specific error being raised is no valid subset found.
What is the general pattern for arguments fed to sympy.solve that produce this error? I can produce examples, but am yet to understand the general pattern (and hence the underlying cause). Moreover, very slight modifications to examples turn them into non-examples.
A secondary question, is there a workaround to get the solve function to succeed when computing w.r.t. to such larger variable sets?
Here are some minimal examples and non-examples showing the surprising behavior and illustrating how the behavior is hard to predict:
The following block including its various solve lines all execute without raising an error.
from sympy import symbols, solve
a1,a2,a3,a4,a5=symbols(['a1','a2','a3','a4','a5'])
eqnSystem0=[-8*a1, a1]
eqnSystem1=[-8*a1, a1**2]
eqnSystem2=[a1**2*a2 - 2*a2**3,16*a1**3 + 4*a1*a2**2]
eqnSystem3=[8*a1**4*a2 + 4*a1**2*a2**3 - 8*a1**2*a2*a4 + a2**5/2 - 2*a2**3*a4 + 8*a2*a3**2 + 2*a2*a4**2 + 8*a2*a5, 12*a1**4 + 6*a1**2*a2**2 - 8*a1**2*a4 + 3*a2**4/4 - 2*a2**2*a4 + 4*a3**2 + a4**2 + 4*a5, 16*a1**3 + 4*a1*a2**2 - 8*a1*a4, -8*a1**2*a2 - 2*a2**3 + 4*a2*a4]
solve(eqnSystem0,[a1,a2],dict=True)
solve(eqnSystem1,[a1,a2],dict=True)
solve(eqnSystem2,[a1,a2],dict=True)
solve(eqnSystem3,[a1,a2,a3,a4],dict=True)

These next solve commands also execute without error.
solve(eqnSystem0,[a1,a2,a3],dict=True)
solve(eqnSystem2,[a1,a2,a3],dict=True)

But these next two each raise the error no valid subset found.
solve(eqnSystem1,[a1,a2,a3],dict=True)
solve(eqnSystem3,[a1,a2,a3,a4,a5],dict=True)

Why is the error being raised for eqnSystem1 and eqnSystem3 but not for eqnSystem0 and eqnSystem2?

This is a bug. Please open a GitHub issue: https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues

@OscarBenjamin, Thanks, I have opened the issue there.

https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/27001

A pull request fixing this has been submitted. A workaround is to pass only the subset of variables of interest:
def solve_sys(eqs, syms):
    free = Tuple(*eqs).free_symbols
    sub = set(syms) & free
    if len(sub) == len(syms) and len(sub) <= len(eqs):
        return solve(eqs, syms, dict=True)
    for s in subsets(sub, min(len(sub),len(eqs))):
        try:
            return solve(eqs, s, dict=True)
        except:
            pass
    assert None, 'no valid subset'

e.g.
from sympy import *
from sympy.abc import x, y, z
>>> solve_sys((x,x**2),(x,y,z))
[{x: 0, z: z, y: y}]

>>> solve_sys(eqnSystem3, [a1,a2,a3,a4,a5])
[{a3: -sqrt(-a5), a4: 2*a1**2 + a2**2/2}, {a3: sqrt(-a5), a4: 2*a1**2 + a2**2/2}, {a1: 0, a2: 0, a3: -sqrt(-a4**2 - 4*a5)/2}, {a1: 0, a2: 0, a3: sqrt(-a4**2 - 4*a5)/2}, {a1: 0, a3: -sqrt(-a5), a4: a2**2/2}, {a1: 0, a3: sqrt(-a5), a4: a2**2/2}]


Thank you. This workaround does not always succeed though because the error raised is unrelated to whether or not all of the variables appear in the equation system. It is rather a coincidence that removing such superfluous variables resolves the issue in the minimal example system (x,x**2). I have edited the original post to add a more intricate example (see the new eqnSystem3 example there), and that example produces again the same error while having all variables present in the system.

I think that's failing for a different reason. In the first case because both variables couldn't be given unique values (because one was missing); the second case because a solution cannot be returned for the desired variables (which are present). Try the Groebner basis approach discussed/referenced on the issue.

The Groebner basis is a good idea, thanks. Regarding the former case, solve([x,x**2],[x,y]) succeeds even though y is not constrained to a unique value. Yet solve([x,x**2],[x,y,z]) fails. Regarding the second case, there are, however, several solutions that can be found with respect to a1,...,a4 and indeed solve(eqnSystem3,[a1,a2,a3,a4],dict=True) succeeds in finding them. Yet  solve(eqnSystem3,[a1,a2,a3,a4,a5],dict=True) fails.

solve([x,x**2],[x,y,z]) succeeds with the most recent SymPy (containing the fix I suggested). Your second example shows that one must iterate over subsets that do not exceed the length of the set of equations. I am updating the code snippet above and will open a PR making that additional change. Your feedback has been very helpful.
